# URL Segment. Correct URL and bad link

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a correctly set URL Segment, e.g. /nieruchomosci

but the page 
https://www.remax-prestige.pl/typo3-95/nieruchomosci

opens incorrectly. The home page ("/home") opens with login instead of page "/nieruchomości"

This situation is with every page - not only with the page /nieruchomosci
eg. "/nieruchomosci/domy"
https://www.remax-prestige.pl/typo3-95/nieruchomosci/domy

This problem does not occur on my computer, but on all the others computers  I checked.

===============

My explanation. I have now changed the installation - it is in the directory https://www.remax-prestige.pl/t3/

I have the primary index.html file - that I want to be in root - it's opens correctly.

But when I want to enter the typo3 system through any link, e.g. LINK in navigation (https://www.remax-prestige.pl/t3/team) the index.php incorrectly opens.

But this applies to all other links, e.g. from each section below the counter. e.g. Mieszkania >> wybierz nieruchomość. https://www.remax-prestige.pl/t3/nieruchomosci

the index.php page also opens

When I enter, for example, the link >> https://www.remax-prestige.pl/t3/nieruchomosci

Perhaps the problem is in shortcut. How can I do a shortcut to index.html? I do not see such a possibility from the TYPO3 level - it can not see the index.html file. Here is a lot of instability - sometimes it opens correctly, sometimes not.

Both file - Home (as shortcut, and Home as index.php) are excluded from menu.

Answer (score 0):

just for clarification:
I assume your TYPO3 installation is inside a subdirectory `typo3-95/` of the webroot.
When you talk from `/home` you mean `https://www.remax-prestige.pl/typo3-95/home`

but what is

> The home page ("/home") opens with login

do you mean a backend login? do you have a login on your start page (`/home`)? do you have access (login) restricted pages?

---

two possible problems:

TYPO3 9LTS and it's new internal URL handling gets confused with the initial subdirectory.
in general and especially if it starts with `typo3`, which is the entry to the backend, which starts with a login.

---

your further explanations hint to another detail:

as these URLs are virtual TYPO3 uses a rewrite mechanism of the webserver, which redirects every request to the base file in TYPO3: /index.php
if you have TYPO3 in a subfolder this redirects points into the wrong folder. You need to adapt the `.htaccess` and change the redirect to your subfolder.